# XPages RichText Links

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino, richtext

I have an XPage to display document data. To display RichText data I added a RichText control. What I found out is that database / view / document links are displayed with the appropriate icon but are converted to http-links. I would like to have these links being transformed to notes://-links to make sure that these links are being opened in the user's notes client rather than in the user's browser. 
Any suggestions how to accomplish this from a technical point of view?

Many thanks in advance for your help. 
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speak after me:

```
 The web knows no RichText, it is a ghost of Christmas past.
 There is only MIME. Now go and live with it!
```

Unless you build an hybrid application where RichText is used in the client and browser I recommend to select the option [x] Save as MIME in the RichText options. For hybrid applications it depends on the use case.

In your case it seems (?) that the datbase/view/document links are added using a client. It looks like a good idea to use mime in this case. Then is is just a simple string (of HTML) where you can before display (or save) use a DOM operation or a Regex to sort out the content. That works client or server side

You could have a custom control that contains a DIV and a XSP.addOnLoad() script that uses the [RichtText url](http://www.iminstant.com/iminstant/iminstant.nsf/d6plinks/ctyr-7h6s6r) in an Ajax call and a `dojo.query("a")` to get a handle on all links and then sort out the ones you want to alter.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I think I will tell my users to paste notes-links manually as there are only a few documents affected. Anyway, thanks for your assistance. It's very much appreciated.