# Converting richtext to MIME / HTML?

Tags: xpages

I have a old Notes Database that was designed with tradtional Notes forms for both the client and the web.

I still want to keep the old database in the traditonal Notes client.   But display the rich text as HTML in xpages.

I selected the Store contents as HTML and MIME on the rich text field on the form but when I do, it destroys all of the formatting and removes things like collapsable sections.  But it does allow the content to be displayed even though it is not pretty.

I found this thread:
[XPages RichText Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933282/xpages-richtext-links)

Where Steve recommends using that option.

He goes on with a further solution that I am not sure I understand it at all.

We have lots and lots of content, so asking the users to redo it all manaully is not an option.  Is there anyway we can either just display this rich text content or at least convert it while keeping all of the formatting and collapsible sections?

Comment: Bruce, you can display the Notes rich text content directly with the rich text control. You don't need to convert it. Maybe I don't understand your issue?

Comment: I tried a rich text control and it did not work till I set that store as mime feature but I will check again

Comment: Well no idea why it was not working before but it works now.    The only issue is the collapsable sections do not operate as collapsable sections.   They show as blue text with the text inside them displaying under the "section title".    Anyway to get collapsable sections working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check that option you destroy the existing content formatting if you don't convert the content. The conversion is not perfect and is what the RichText control does on the fly. 
The set of actions you want to take:

- get the coexedit plugin or the
- add a new RT field with the MIME
- run an agent to
- optional: remove the old field and rename the new to the old name (make sure mime stays checked)

For read only access (both options get better with the coexedit plugin) :

- use the RichText control, no further action is required
- use a Dojo panel. It has a href property you point to ... Body?OpenField, no further action is required

Note:the later doesn't work in XPiNC

Comment: Looks like the rich text control is working for me (sort of). I don't need to have to edit on the web.  Just display. No real need to convert then.  So I am good and won't see other issues? The one issue I am seeing is that the collapsable sections do not collpase. Any way to get that to work?

Comment: The coexedit plugin works there to. Deploy to server, sit back and enjoy. And when you need to edit,  you know what to do. Works for classic Web too. AFAIK there is a trial version.  Tell Ben I send my regards

Comment: Will the coexedit control get me my collapasible sections back? Our admins are not too keen on deploying 3rd party products so it might be moot.

Comment: Get a trial and check it out on your test server on your local laptop. For Admins who are not keen to assist in solving business problems there are coffee sessions with gentlemen that sport lots of tattoo